# Problem with loading big data (GeoJSON) via PHP

Tags: javascript, geojson, php, jquery

I have a problem with loading (big) data via PHP from a spatial database. I let run this project on a localhost Apache Server.
From a data count of about 30.000 edges I get an error

```js
VM885:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (test.html:197)
    at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

For a smaller amount of data there is no problem and I can easily display the data. So I guess the php-script works.

Why does this happen?

I am calling a php-file via AJAX call (with a parameter which represent the amount of data I want to receive - I do it simply with the ID).

```js
function refreshEdges(whr, callback) {
            if(whr) {
                var objData = {tbl:'laendliches_strassennetz', where:whr};
                } else {
                    var objData = {tbl:'laendliches_strassennetz'};
                }
            $.ajax({
                url:'php/load_data.php',
                data: objData,
                type:'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.substring(0,5)=="ERROR") {
                        alert("ERROR: "+response);
                        callback(false);
                    } else {
                        jsnEdges=JSON.parse(response);
                        if (lyrEdges) {
                            lyrEdges.remove();
                        }
                        callback(jsnEdges);
                    }
                }, error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("ERROR: "+error);
                }
            });
        }
```

The answer will be handled by a callback function.

```js
var anzahl = $("#loadDataAnzahl").val();
refreshEdges("id < "+anzahl, function(response){
  if(response) {
    lyrEdges = L.geoJSON(response).addTo(mymap);
    });
```

The php-file just loads data from a spatial database and send it back as a GeoJSON Feature Collection.

```php
$table = $_POST['tbl'];
if (isset($_POST['where'])) {
            $where = " WHERE ".$_POST['where'];
        } else {
            $where = "";
        }
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT {$fields}, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS geojson FROM {$table} {$where}");  
$features=[];
                foreach($result AS $row) {
                    unset($row['geom']);
                    $geometry=$row['geojson']=json_decode($row['geojson']);
                    unset($row['geojson']);
                    $feature=["type"=>"Feature", "geometry"=>$geometry, "properties"=>$row];
                    array_push($features, $feature);
                }
                $featureCollection=["type"=>"FeatureCollection", "features"=>$features];
                echo json_encode($featureCollection);
```